# Checking if user exists on registration page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, connection-string, registration

I am trying to check if the username entered is already in the database table called Table in the Column called name. If not already used it can be entered into table, I have checked the insert code seperatle and it works fine.

```
    protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = tbUser.Text;
        string pass = tbPass.Text;


        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string checkUser = "select Count(*) from dbo.Table where name = '"+name+"'";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(checkUser, connection);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                lblError.Text = "Username Taken";
            }
            else
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] VALUES(@name, @pass)";

                command.Parameters.Add("@name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = name;
                command.Parameters.Add("@pass", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = GetMd5Hash(pass);

                int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

error i get is, 
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

Comment: Is your table name really table? Please no. Also, why aren't you using SQL params for the first query like you are for the second? You are open to a SQL injection there

Comment: May be use SQL params for name.

Comment: The problem appears to be in this line `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]`. It should be something like `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users]`, check your database for correct table name. Also, your first call to the db is vulnerable to SQL injection, use parametrised query instead.

Comment: table is keyword in SQL server, you can use keyword yes, but sometime will case issues, I like to point to use one of ADO framework to deal with data base Instead of writing all these lines..  take a look at http://www.geniusescode.com/en/Index.html

Comment: yes the table is called Table as its only quit example to try and get it to work then put it into my main project where the tables are correctly named

Comment: Also try to refactor the database calling logic into a business layer class, having DB-calls in event handlers is bad design and will lead to cluttered code with poor maintainability...

Comment: Use parametrised query and change dbo.Table to dbo.[Table]. This will tell the Sql that "table" is not a keyword but a name of your table.

Comment: changed dbo.Table to [dbo].[Table], silly error my brain is fried working on this thanks for all yere help

Answer (score 0):

**Error** occurs in this line.

```
string checkUser = "select Count(*) from dbo.Table where name = '"+name+"'";
```

**Solution:**

You need to place the Table in [] bracket.

```
string checkUser = "select Count(*) from [dbo].[Table] where name = '"+name+"'";
```

**Information:**

```
"Reserved keywords should not be used as object names. Databases upgraded from 
earlier versions of SQL Server may contain identifiers that include words not reserved 
in the earlier version, but that are reserved words for the current version of SQL Server.
You can refer to the object by using delimited identifiers until the name can be 
changed." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027.aspx
```

and

```
    "If your database does contain names that match reserved keywords, you must 
use delimited identifiers when you refer to those objects. For more information, 
see Identifiers (DMX)." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132178.aspx
```